# A tricky SQL statement using 3 tables with a status check

Tags: mysql, sql

maybe someone could shed some light on the statement that I have been battling with the entire day :)

I have 3 tables

**Holiday**

```
holidayID | userID | dateFrom   | dateTo
1         |      1 | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-01
2         |      1 | 2012-01-15 | 2012-01-20
```

**Status**

```
statusID | holidayID | statusText
1        |         1 | accepted
2        |         2 | declined
```

**UserSettings**

```
id | userID | HolidaysAllowed
1  |      1 | 20
```

What I am trying to do is get the following result

**Result**

```
HolidaysAllowed | HolidaysLeft (Allowed - Taken) | HolidaysTaken (Sum of Holidays)
20              |                             19 |      1
```

I am able to get all three columns if I dont state a status - here is the closest I got

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(SUM( IF(  h.dateTo = h.dateFrom, 1, DATEDIFF( h.dateTo, h.dateFrom ) ) ), 0) AS holidaysTaken, 
IFNULL(us.HolidaysAllowed - ( SUM(  IF(  h.DateTo = h.DateFrom, 1, DATEDIFF( h.DateTo, h.dateFrom ) ) ) ), 0) AS holidaysLeftover, 
us.HolidaysAllowed
FROM userSettings us 
LEFT JOIN holiday h 
ON h.userID = 1 
JOIN status s 
ON s.holidayID = h.holidayID AND s.statusID = 1 
WHERE 
us.userID = 1
GROUP BY h.userID;
```

The main problem is that if there is no holiday with statusID = 2 then result column 1 & 2 are 0 (which is correct) but column 3 (HolidaysAllowed) is NULL (incorrect as it needs to always return the value from the table UserSettings). The above query only returns a correct response when there is at least 1 record (holiday) with the correct status... what am I doing wrong? :)

Its just driving me nuts :) Thanks in advance for any help! Much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to everyone who commented... the expected result is as follows
Get all holidays that have a status = 1 (i.e accepted) then calculate the holidays statistics against that of the holidays allowed. I.e.

20 days in total, 1 holiday accepted = 19 days left to take

thanks again

Comment: Can you post some sample data and desired o/p

Comment: @Vutukuri - thanks for your comments... i have updated my question. Siva... statusID can have n number of possibilities.

Comment: What about weekend days? Should we assume Saturday/Sunday don't count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT u.userID, u.HolidaysAllowed,
u.holidaysAllowed - 
COALESCE( 
    (SELECT SUM( DATEDIFF( h1.dateTo, h1.dateFrom) + 1) 
         FROM holiday h1 
         INNER JOIN status s1
         ON s1.holidayID = h1.holidayID
         WHERE h1.userID = u.userID
         AND s1.statusID = 1
     ), 0) AS HolidaysLeft,
COALESCE( 
    (SELECT SUM( DATEDIFF( h2.dateTo, h2.dateFrom) + 1) 
         FROM holiday h2 
         INNER JOIN status s2
         ON s2.holidayID = h2.holidayID
         WHERE h2.userID = u.userID
         AND s2.statusID = 1
     ), 0) AS HolidaysTaken
FROM userSettings u
;
```

Comment: This query assumes that each from/to duration defined in the holidays table includes business days only and not weekends, so a two week holiday would need to be defined as a pair of M-F holidays. It also assumes that there are no holiday records from previous reporting periods, such as last year.

Answer (score 2):

Following query doesn't take weekends into consideration.

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5267/6)

*Script*:

```
CREATE TABLE Holiday 
(       
        holidayid   INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,   userid      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
    ,   dateFrom    DATETIME    NOT NULL 
    ,   dateTo      DATETIME    NOT NULL 
    ,   PRIMARY KEY(holidayid)
);

CREATE TABLE Status
(       
        id          INT         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,   holidayid   INT         NOT NULL
    ,   statusid    INT         NOT NULL
    ,   PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE UserSettings
(       
        id              INT     NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,   userid          INT     NOT NULL
    ,   HolidaysAllowed INT     NOT NULL
    ,   PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO  Holiday (userid, dateFrom, dateTo) VALUES
    (1, '2012-04-01', '2012-04-03'),
    (2, '2012-04-04', '2012-04-05'),
    (2, '2012-04-07', '2012-04-09'),
    (3, '2012-04-09', '2012-04-12'),
    (3, '2012-04-16', '2012-04-16'),
    (1, '2012-04-19', '2012-04-22');

INSERT INTO  Status (holidayid, statusid) VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 1),
    (5, 2),
    (6, 2);

INSERT INTO  UserSettings (userid, HolidaysAllowed) VALUES
    (1, 5),
    (2, 10),
    (3, 7),
    (4, 6);


SELECT  u.userid
    ,   u.HolidaysAllowed
    ,   u.HolidaysAllowed - COALESCE(hol.HolidaysTaken, 0) AS HolidaysLeft
    ,   COALESCE(hol.HolidaysTaken, 0) AS HolidaysTaken
FROM
(
    SELECT          h.userid
                ,   ABS(SUM(
                      CASE 
                        WHEN statusid = 1 THEN DATEDIFF(dateTo, dateFrom) + 1
                        ELSE 0 END
                    )) HolidaysTaken

    FROM            UserSettings    us
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Holiday         h
    ON              us.userid       = h.userid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Status          s
    ON              s.holidayid     = h.holidayid
    GROUP BY        h.userid
)                   hol
RIGHT OUTER JOIN    UserSettings u
ON                  u.userid = hol.userid;
```

*Output*:

```
USERID HOLIDAYSALLOWED HOLIDAYSLEFT HOLIDAYSTAKEN
------ --------------- ------------ -------------
1             5              5            0
2            10              5            5
3             7              3            4
4             6              6            0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.HolidaysAllowed AS HolidaysAllowed,
       B.HolidaysAllowed-A.HolidaysTaken AS HolidaysLeft,
       A.HolidaysTaken AS HolidaysTaken
FROM
(
 SELECT A.userID,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(A.dateTo,A.dateFom)=0
                          THEN 1
                          ELSE DATEDIFF(A.dateTo,A.dateFom)
                    ) AS HolidaysTaken
 FROM Holiday A,Status B
 WHERE A.holidayID = B.holidayID
   AND A.statusText='accepted'
 GROUP BY useID
) A,
UserSettings B
WHERE A.userID = B.userID;
```

Comment: This query as it stands right now is actually less correct than the original version posted in the question. It does not check the status table to determine whether the holiday is accepted or declined, it doesn't compute single-day holidays properly, and it doesn't handle the NULL that will be encountered for employees who have yet to use any holidays.

Comment: It's still incorrect. DATEDIFF cannot be used by itself to calculate the number of days the holiday covers, since DATEDIFF never includes the first day in its answer. The original question requires a Monday through Friday holiday to be reported as five days, not the four day duration that DATEDIFF will give you when you tell it to subtract Monday's date from Friday's date.